# How do I track form submissions in Tag Manager, based on the class name of the div surrounding it?

Tags: google-tag-manager, form-submit

I have a web page with several forms on, and none of the forms have a unique identifier to hook onto to know which form submission is which for when it appears in Analytics.

The agency I work with have added a unique class name to the div wrapping around the form, and said to use that, which doesn't seem robust. Even so, how do I track form submissions using the class name of the parent div element?

Is it even possible in Tag Manager?

The agency tried implementing a class/ID onto the form itself, though that requires hacking the CMS plugin by hard coding it.

If I don't get a response, I am going to try and track it based on the Form Element variable available in Tag Manager.

Comment: We will need additional information, like the code snippet of the form, in order to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to track form submissions.

First, GTM has a native form submission listener, but modern forms now rarely use that mechanism, and I believe this was the first thing you'd try.

Second, you can track the form submit button clicks, maybe also run some GTM validation of the fields on the click to make sure you're not counting obvious errors as conversions, and you also could have a blocker logic to prevent this event from firing for the same session more than once, if a user reloads the page and tries to resubmit it or something like that.

Finally, the proper solution would be tracking the form submission in the callback of the submission request. Maybe the form is already kind enough to issue a window message on submits. You could deploy a window message listener and see what messages are sent on deploy, then use it as a trigger for your form submit logic.

I don't see the need to implement class/id on the form. For easier selectors? This doesn't justify the work.